# Synchronizing e-mail using one IMAP and one POP client

Tags: email, sync, imap, email-client, pop3

OK I have an odd situation:

I need to synchronize e-mail from a single e-mail account on a single server to two different e-mail clients.
I need e-mail to be removed from the e-mail server.

I've tried setting up these accounts so that one uses POP to remove and sync e-mails and the other uses IMAP to sync e-mails, but this simply creates a race condition between the clients. and results in only some e-mails being delivered to the IMAP client.

Does anyone know of a better way to accomplish my goals?

Comment: I'm confused. IMAP requires e-mails to be server side, yet you want them to sync AND have e-mails removed server side? This is an incompatible request.

Comment: IMAP doesn't actually REQUIRE that, it is simply the normal operation. Nothing stops you removing the emails whenever you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to get messy I think.

You will have to have both clients connect using IMAP as nothing else will work. Then you will need to find a way to get both clients to indicate they have finished replicating, then you will need a server process that recognises that signal and deletes the emails. Not good. What happens as more email comes in while the clients are replicating? I think that you would have to stop the email server first - see what I mean about messy?

So, lets wind back slightly. *Why* do you want to do that? If you can explain that, I'd be prepared to bet that we can come up with a better approach.

Comment: You're right; I do need to rethink my planned implementation. For instance synchronizing changes to e-mails is just worth too much effort.